# How to increase throughput in Informatica PowerCenter 10 for FileReader

Tags: xml, filereader, informatica-powercenter, throughput

[image: Performance Coun[![enter image description here]ter[][1][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tNMg4.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4xMFq.png)[image]I have a workflow with XML data read from files using XML Parser transformation. It has 12 target tables to load them. Currently it is working successfully, but the problem is Throughput(Rows/Sec) while reading the data from files. With number of files 10 or less it provides through put of 10 rows/sec. But if I provide more than 10 rows, then initially at the start of workflow throughput is 4 to 5 rows/sec and then suddenly drops to 1 row/sec. And it remains 1 row/sec for all the files. Some times I have 300 or 400 files and it takes too much time just to read these 300 400 rows with the throughout of 1 row/sec.

I have tried to improve by increasing the DTM buffer and default block size values. 
I have also tried "Dynamic Partitioning Option" to "Based on number of Partitions".

But no success.

Comment: Check the statistics from the session log, you can find at the end of the log file. if possible please paste that here, it will help us to understand where the bottleneck.

Comment: I have added the stats screenshot

Comment: By this I have come to know that the bottleneck is the transformation thread. And in which, JNR_DeviationEnabled took the most of time.

Comment: To measure performance, I have checked the "Collect Performance Data" and "Write Performance Data to Repository". I have attached the performance counters, Can anyone please describe what are they numbers saying?

Comment: Just as indicated in the log: it's the Joiners that are causing the issue. Please check the amount of data/index cache information. How is the caching configured for the two joiners? How many join conditions are there?

Comment: Source is XML, and in my mapping for there are 4 joiners only before that target. Out of those 4 joiners one is this which is taking most time. I tried to add sorter before the first joiner but it took more time than before. For caching, the data cache size is 419430480 and Index cache is Auto.

Comment: So, the 2 joins were causing the issues. I applied sorter transformation before both joins. It is working for one joiner but for the second one it is "SORT_40414 Error: Total row size [209715236] in transformation [Sorter_ModelDisPercentage] is more than the allowed maximum [8388607]". Does anyone know about this?

Comment: So the issue has been resolved by reduce the precision values of ports in sorter transformation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned from the session log stats the 2 joiners were the bottleneck as their busy percentage is almost 100 percent. So I have added sorters before those joiners and then make the precision values less in order to avoid the sorter row size limit of 8MB. Now the throughput is also increased and equal to the number of files /sec rather than one row/sec.